# How to answer the buzzfizz question using For loop

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

```js
for (var a = 1; a < 101; a++) {
  if (a % 3 === 0 && a % 5 === 0) {
    console.log("buzztuf");
  } else if (a % 3 === 0) {
    console.log("buzz");
  } else if (a % 5 === 0) {
    console.log("tuf");
  } else {
    console.log(a);
  }
}
```

The current implementation produces both numbers and strings as output. However, it is required to remove numbers when the corresponding string is present.

Comment: where `string` and `number` present simultaneously?

Comment: I meant instead of showing just buzz in the place of 3 it was showing both 3 and buss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your implementation, unless I am misunderstanding the question, is correct.

Some optimisations you may consider are:

Rewriting the `a % 3 === 0 && a % 5 === 0` expression to `a % 15 == 0` as any value where `a % 3 === 0` and `a % 5 === 0` are simultaneously true are also true when `a % 15`.

And also rewriting the if statements to

```js
if (a % 15 === 0) console.log("buzztuf");
else if (a % 3 === 0) console.log("buzz");
else if (a % 5 === 0) console.log("tuf");
else console.log(a);
```

This is valid syntax as if a statement is written directly after an if, else or else if statement, it will be executed as if it was written within the scope of curly braces immediately succeeding the if statement.

Happy coding!